Limit of a sum with binomial coefficients
How can we show that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j{n-k+j\choose j}{n\choose k-j-1}\Bigl(1-\frac{e^{-x}}n\Bigr)^j\to\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(e^{-x})^j}{j!}
$$
as $n\to\infty$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$?
It is not difficult to show that this holds for $k=1,2,3$. Using the definition of the binomial coefficient, we can rewrite the sum in the following way
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\frac1{(n-k+j+1)(k-j-1)!j!}\Bigl(1-\frac{e^{-x}}n\Bigr)^j.
$$
However, it does not seem possible to consider the limit on the term-by-term basis because the factor in front of the sum grows as $n^k$ while the terms of the sum do not go to $0$ sufficiently quickly. Somehow the terms of the sum interact and cancel each other but not in a simple way. I also tried induction but I cannot find a way to show that if the statement holds for $k$, then it also holds for $k+1$. So I am stuck.
Any help is much appreciated!

Seeking to show
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (-1)^j {n-k+j\choose j} {n\choose k-j-1}
(1-\exp(-x)/n)^j \rightarrow
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{\exp(-jx)}{j!}$$
as  $n\rightarrow\infty$  we  observe that  the  second
binomial  coefficient enforces  the  range  and we  may
write
$$[z^{k-1}] (1+z)^n
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j {n-k+j\choose j} z^j
(1-\exp(-x)/n)^j
\\ = [z^{k-1}] (1+z)^n
\frac{1}{(1+z(1-\exp(-x)/n))^{n-k+1}}.$$
This is
$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^k}  (1+z)^n
\frac{1}{(1+z(1-\exp(-x)/n))^{n-k+1}}.$$
Now  put  $z/(1+z)=u$ so  that  $z=u/(1-u)$  and $dz  =
1/(1-u)^2 \; du$ to get
$$\;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^k} \frac{1}{(1-u)^{n-k}}
\frac{1}{(1+u(1-\exp(-x)/n)/(1-u))^{n-k+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-u)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^k} \frac{1}{1-u}
\frac{1}{(1-u+u(1-\exp(-x)/n))^{n-k+1}}
\\ = \;\underset{u}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{u^k} \frac{1}{1-u}
\frac{1}{(1-u\exp(-x)/n)^{n-k+1}}.$$
Do the extraction to get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} {n-k+j\choose j} \exp(-x)^j / n^j
= 1+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\exp(-x)^j}{j!}
\prod_{q=1}^j \frac{n-k+q}{n}
\\ = 1+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \frac{\exp(-x)^j}{j!}
\prod_{q=1}^j (1-(k-q)/n).$$
Now importantly we are keeping  $k$ fixed which gives a
finite sum and a finite multiplier whose ranges do not
depend on $n$  and hence we may take the  limit on the
factors  of  the  product  which  gives  one  for  each
factor, and collecting the two terms we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{\exp(-x)^j}{j!}$$
which is the claim.

Thanks a lot for your answer (+1)! I am unfamiliar with this proof technique so it would be great if you could clarify some points. (a) What do you mean by that the second binomial coefficient enforces the range? (b) Does $\mathop{\operatorname{res}}_z$ stand for the residue of a function? How can we conclude this specific form of the residue? (c) What kind of extraction do we need to do?

(a) It goes zero when $j\gt k-1.$ (b) Yes, this is the residue at zero. The notation is from the book Combinatorial Sums by Egorychev. (c) The extraction refers to extracting the coefficient from a Laurent/Taylor series. See Wikipedia.
